# Moving code from Xcode 3 to 4 produces error: Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, compiler-errors, instance-variables, class-extensions

I am migrating my old iPhone apps from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4.  I receive this error on code which used to build in Xcode 3 -- in fact I wrote it this way on purpose to hide implementation details from other modules.  However, something seems to have changed in  Objective-C.  This code now receives the error

> Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol.

Remember, this is code at the top of the .m file not the .h

```
@interface VisualViewController ()
BOOL doReloadPhoto;

+ (void)buildVisualEffectInfo;

@property (nonatomic, retain) HandleCheckListSetting *checkListHandler;
@end
```

Answer (score 9):

This may have compiled before, but I don't think it was doing what you think it's doing. It sounds like you want to create a private ivar in a class extension. The syntax you have is just a top-level variable, though, equivalent to:

```
BOOL doReloadPhoto;

@interface VisualViewController ()
// etc.
@end
```

You need to put it inside curly braces for it to be an ivar:

```
@interface VisualViewController () 
{
    BOOL doReloadPhoto;
}
```

(Conversely, I'm not sure that this -- ivar in extension -- was possible with Xcode 3's compiler, which is probably why you did it the way you did.) It sounds like the compiler is now (sensibly) pointing out that the code you have probably isn't doing what you expect, and forcing you to make your intention completely clear.

It has also recenty become possible to declare private ivars in the `@implementation` block, using the same syntax:

```
@implementation VisualViewController
{
    BOOL doReloadPhoto;
}
```

Comment: Whoa I had no idea you could do that in the implementation now. Way cool.

Comment: @Jack: This is actually now Apple's recommended practice. I love it. It makes a million times more sense; ivars are indeed part of the implementation, not the interface.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau +1. I didn't know that either. You learn something new every day. ;)